# How to create the full set of dependencies of my dictionary data in python using recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

The program should use this data to calculate the full set of dependencies. For example, looking at B, we see it directly depends on C and E. C in turn relies on G, E relies on F, and F relies on H. This means that B ultimately relies on C, E, F, G, and H.

```
input_data ={
    "A":["B","C"],
    "B":["C","E"],
    "C":["G"],
    "D":["A","F"],
    "E":["F"],
    "F":["H"]
}
```

output will be the reference of for all of dependent values.

```
output ={
    "A":["B","C","E","F","G","H"],
    "B":["C","E","F","G","H"],
    "C":["G"],
    "D":["A","B","C","E","F","G","H"],
    "E":["F","H"],
    "F":["H"]
}
```

If possible I want try it with recursion

I tried something like this

```
import copy
output = copy.deepcopy(input_data)

def rec_update(key, values):
    for value in values:
        if not input_data .get(value):
            if not value in output[key]:
                output[key].append(value)
        else:
            rec_update(value, input_data .get(value))

for key, values in input_data .items():
    rec_update(key, values)
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: btw don't use `input` as a variable name. It is a built-in.

Comment: added details expectation of what I am looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion. Firstly we create a function that iterates through the input_data for x, adding new child items. It stops when no new child items are found. Then we apply this function on all keys of input_data:

```
input_data ={
    "A":["B","C"],
    "B":["C","E"],
    "C":["G"],
    "D":["A","F"],
    "E":["F"],
    "F":["H"]
}

def f(x):
    res=[]
    new=input_data[x]
    while new!=[]:
        res.extend([i for i in new if i not in res])
        temp=[]
        for i in res:
            if input_data.get(i):
                temp.extend(input_data.get(i))
        new=[k for k in temp if k not in res]
    return res

output={i:f(i) for i in input_data}

print(output)
```

Result:

```
{'A': ['B', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'F', 'H'], 'B': ['C', 'E', 'G', 'F', 'H'], 'C': ['G'], 'D': ['A', 'F', 'B', 'C', 'H', 'E', 'G'], 'E': ['F', 'H'], 'F': ['H']}
```